# Printing image from imageview :xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, airprint

Can anyone tell me how to print image from imageview with  UIPrintInteractionController.
Thanks

Comment: Life (and learning how to program) is largely self-serve: http://www.google.com/search?q=UIPrintInteractionController

Answer (score 1):

First read about AirPrinter and how to use it.Follow the link:
https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/blob/master/AirPrinter/AirPrinter

You need to add the files **UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer.h** and **UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer.m**

Get it from here :

https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/blob/master/AirPrinter/AirPrinter/UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer.h

https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/blob/master/AirPrinter/AirPrinter/UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer.m

These are the PrintPageRenderer files.

Import this file in your class :

```
#import "UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer.h"
```

Now check for your device supports printing or not :

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]) {

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(printImageView)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButton animated:NO];
    self.printButton = barButton;
    [barButton release];

}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sorry, Printing is not available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Now print the image which is "printImageView" as used here as the object of UIImageView class.

```
- (void)printImageView{

UIPrintInteractionController *pc = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = @"Sample Print";
pc.printInfo = printInfo;
pc.showsPageRange = YES;

UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer *renderer = [[UYLGenericPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
renderer.headerText = printInfo.jobName;
renderer.footerText = @"AirPrinter Sample";

UIViewPrintFormatter *formatter = [printImageView viewPrintFormatter];
[renderer addPrintFormatter:formatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
pc.printPageRenderer = renderer;
[renderer release];

UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = 
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if(!completed && error){
        DLog(@"Print failed - domain: %@ error code %u", error.domain, error.code); 
    }
};

    [pc presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert image to pdf and print the pdf.